# How extract a string from path using regex?

Tags: regex, string, joomla, sublimetext2

First thanks to try help me!

I need extract string "videos" from this path directory:

`/D/Servers/Domain/www/domain.com/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php`

How proceed to solve this issue?

Comment: To get an answer you should post some code to prove that you already tried doing this yourself. It's a Q&A site, but has its own rules.http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Read them and apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's title clearly states he wants a regex solution.

So the regex you're looking for is:

```
/(\w+)\.php$/
```

Comment: The question is clearly an X-Y Problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 3):

I do not think, that regular expressions are needed there.

One way is to use [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) + [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) functions:

```
<?php    
$path = '/D/Servers/Domain/www/domain.com/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php';

echo strstr(basename($path), '.', true);
?>
```

Shows:

```
videos
```

---

Another way is to use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/path-info):

```
<?php
$path = '/D/Servers/Domain/www/domain.com/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php';

echo pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
?>
```

Shows:

```
videos
```

Comment: So funny how competing questions evolve over the first few minutes

Comment: Thanks to help, but I need to use with Sublime Text 2, in a Snippet file, I need the regex to do it...

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the extension will always be `.php`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
$path = "/D/Servers/Domain/www/domain.com/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php";
basename($path, ".php"); // returns "videos.php"
```

---

Alternatively, if you do not know the extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$path = "/D/Servers/Domain/www/domain.com/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php";
$pathinfo = pathinfo($path);
$pathinfo['filename']; // equals "videos"
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Lets hope our answers will help OP.

Comment: Thanks to help, but I need to use with Sublime Text 2, in a Snippet file, I need the regex to do it...

Comment: sublime text uses python in its core. There's python that can do this.

Comment: And how about you ask that in your question? Don't you think that's pertinent information?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since this isn't a php question but a sublimetext question, which is actually a python question:

```
import os
path = "/D/Servers/Domain/www/domain.com/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php"
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0] # outpus "videos"
```

Comment: What are you on? This is a PHP and Joomla! question.

Comment: Read the OP's comments on the other answers. This is a sublimetext problem.

Comment: OK I see it now :) Super weird :)

Comment: Yeah it's a pretty bad question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `JPATH` rathing than defining the full path as it's using Joomla coding standards:

```
$path = JPATH_ROOT . "/administrator/components/com_videos/videos.php";
basename($path, ".php");
```